# is there a way to detect German Umlauts in Android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am trying to detect german umlauts with a soft keyboard. To recognize the entered characters I use the method `onKeyUp()`. But this method is not executed for German umlauts.

Is there a way for me to recognize them?

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not a good idea to check for language specific characters with `KeyListener`. For this use case it is better to use `TextWatcher`.

```
object : TextWatcher {

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        val umlaut = "\u00FC"
        if (!s.isNullOrEmpty() && s[count - 1].toString() == umlaut) {
            // Do your thing
        }
    }

    ... 
}
```